# Sitefinity add new function to page text editor

Tags: radeditor, sitefinity-10

I can find a lot of documentation on how to add things to the text editor itself, including a place to [add additional buttons/functions into the XML through the admin settings](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/text-editor-settings).

What I cannot find is where I would then create the new functions that those settings reference. I tried searching my local solution for a few random ones and nothing came up.

For clarification, I'm looking at adding in a button on the editor for pages - or really anywhere in the back end that uses the text editor, but at least in pages. I'm not trying to add a completely new editor in my own widget or something, which would make this really easy as it appears those can [simply be declared inline](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/customtools/defaultcs.aspx).

**Update**

Going to Administration -> Settings -> Text editor and clicking "edit" for "Default tool set" gives me a settings XML sheet something like this. I should be able to just add a new tool here in the XML, but I have no idea where the actual code for that tool should live in order to be used by this editor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <modules>
    <module name="RadEditorStatistics" dockingZone="Bottom" visible="false" />
    <module name="RadEditorDomInspector" visible="false" />
    <module name="RadEditorNodeInspector" visible="false" />
    <module name="RadEditorHtmlInspector" visible="false" />
  </modules>
  <tools name="MainToolbar">
    <tool name="ToggleAdvancedToolbars"/>
    <tool name="Bold" shortcut="CTRL+B"/>
    <tool name="Italic" shortcut="CTRL+I"/>
    <tool separator="true"/>
    <tool name="InsertOrderedList" />
    <tool name="InsertUnorderedList" />
    <tool separator="true"/>
    <tool name="LinkManager" shortcut="CTRL+K"/>
    <tool name="Unlink" shortcut="CTRL+SHIFT+K"/>
    <tool name="ImageManager" shortcut="CTRL+G"/>
    <tool separator="true"/>
    <tool name="AjaxSpellCheck"/>
    <tool separator="true"/>
    <tool name="PasteFromWord" />
    <tool separator="true"/>
    <tool name="FormatBlock"/>
  </tools>
  //...
</root>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you need this only for WebForms (or Hybrid) page? Because the editors for Webforms and MVC are very different. 
The links you provided and the tag all point to WebForms, but I doubt anyone is building new sites with Sitefinity 10 on webforms nowadays, so that's why I am asking :)

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I literally only need this for the existing backend text editors. Definitely running version 10.0.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev hopefully my edit helps clarify things. I don't know much about the inner workings of Sitefinity, I just create simple widgets or style things usually when it comes to this system.